# Does Service Bus Trigger for Azure Function need Manage access rights to Service Bus Queue/Topic?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have found 2 documents from Microsoft that seem (to me at least) to give a conflicting information on whether I should use `Listen` or `Manage` access rights.

> Scale efficiency: For Service Bus triggers, use Manage rights on resources for the most efficient scaling. With Listen rights, scaling isn't as accurate because the queue length can't be used to inform scaling decisions. To learn more about setting rights in Service Bus access policies, see Shared Access Authorization Policy. For Event Hub triggers, see the scaling guidance in the reference article.

From `Event-driven scaling in Azure Functions`  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support#understanding-scaling-behaviors).

> Access rights for the connection string. Available values are manage and listen. The default is manage, which indicates that the connection has the Manage permission. If you use a connection string that does not have the Manage permission, set accessRights to "listen". Otherwise, the Functions runtime might fail trying to do operations that require manage rights. In Azure Functions version 2.x and higher, this property is not available because the latest version of the Service Bus SDK doesn't support manage operations.

From `Azure Service Bus trigger for Azure Functions` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration).

What I read from this is that the first says it's better to use `Manage` access rights, but the second one says it's not even supported. The second doc is not very clear, but it seems that `Listen` is the only option now.

Do I understand something wrong or it's the documentation that is misleading here? Is it worth giving manage access rights or it won't affect anything as the second documentation seem to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems even though `Listen` should be enough, it is not in `Service Bus Trigger` case. I first got a message from Azure Support as well that `Listen` is enough, and it mostly worked. But once a week during rescaling/restarting of app service I got a dead lettered message that never reached my function. The infrastructure in Azure failed, and I got a reply from Microsoft that I need to turn on `Manage` rights, as these rights missing is what caused this (function infrastructure for some reason tries to preform a manage operation and fails handling a message 10 times in a row).

So even though `Manage` should be optional, it seems there are some problem that make it mandatory in reality. I do believe this is a bug in the Azure infrastructure though.

Answer (score 1):

`Listen` should be the only thing the Function needs - especially assuming you will not deploy a v1 Function anymore.

Comment: Does that mean that the first documentation is totally wrong to suggest that Manage will give better scaling?

Comment: Please see my answer below, it seems that after all `Listen` is not quite enough.

Answer (score 1):

`Listen` rights should be enough, `Manage` rights will only cause difference in the sensitivity of scale controller's scale out/in behavior which is mentioned to be "more efficient" in official document; it doesn’t mean `Listen` right will not work at all regarding scaling.

Internally, scale controller has a lot of rules to determine if more workers should be assigned to function app; besides the rule from `Manage` rights,  if you are using `Listen` rights, the rest of the scale in/out rules for dynamic function app still applies(e.g. when the message's queue length is increasing, etc).

Your function app's overall scale out behaviour should not be significantly affected if you are considering which rights is the correct one to use, `Manage` rights just brings one more scale in/out rule.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `Manage` rights seems to not be available in Azure Functions starting from version 2.

Comment: Please see my answer below, it seems that after all `Listen` is not quite enough.